# bootstrap file upload validation not working

Tags: html, twitter-bootstrap

I am using bootstrap file upload,see this website [Here](http://www.srisankaramatrimony.com/cupid/TV/newuser.php)  .all validation should be working in fine  execpt that photo upload,without select any field i want to show error message...

```
<!--Firstname code-->
  <div class="form-group">
        <label class="col-md-3 control-label">First Name<span class="star_mark">&nbsp;*</span></label>
                 <div class="col-sm-6">
                  <input type="text" class="form-control" id="fname" name="fname" value="" aria-required="true" required="" data-msg-required="Please enter your firstname">

                  </div>
                 </div>
  <!-- File uplod code here -->


<div class="form-group">
                      <label class="col-md-3 control-label">Photo Upload</label>
                      <div class="col-md-6">
                      <div class="fileupload fileupload-new" data-provides="fileupload">
                      <div class="input-append">
                      <div class="uneditable-input">
                      <i class="fa fa-file fileupload-exists"></i>
                      <span class="fileupload-preview"></span>
                      </div>
                      <span class="btn btn-default btn-file">
                      <span class="fileupload-exists">Change</span>
                      <span class="fileupload-new">Select file</span>
                      <input type="file" id="photo" name="photo" value="" aria-required="true" required="" data-msg-required="Please select any photo">
                      </span>
                      <a href="#" class="btn btn-default fileupload-exists" data-dismiss="fileupload">Remove</a>
                      </div>
                      </div>
                      </div>
                      </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Just leave required as it is.

```
<input type="file" id="photo" name="photo" value="" aria-required="true" required data-msg-required="Please select any photo">
```

Or you can also try something like

```
<input type="file" id="photo" name="photo" value="" aria-required="true" required="required" data-msg-required="Please select any photo">
```

Both options should work

Comment: Error messge it is comming,but i want to show that error message in next line here it will come on same line ...